# Can I use the Facebook JS SDK without also adding the Facebook Impressions tracker?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I'm currently working on an AngularJS application. The application as it blatantly ignores whether or not you accepted any cookie consent and just places trackers. I am to remove all trackers until a user has accepted the cookie policy.

The application also requires the SDK from Facebook to import some user data (Facebook login required). However, the kit from Facebook that the app currently retrieves also places a Facebook Impression tracker (at least according to Ghostery). The policy allows any external code that is *necessary* for any functionality the application provides. I am not convinced however that this tracker falls within that range.

My question therefore is, is it possible to retrieve a version of the Facebook JavaScript SDK that does not also place a tracker?

Comment: No, there are no such “versions” of the SDK. Facebook has little interest in letting you opt-out of their all-across-the-web user tracking. But since you only need this when the user actually wants to login to your site, I suppose you could make this dependent on your cookie acceptance as well ... just don’t embed the SDK, as long as the user has not signaled consent ...

Comment: @CBroe That's what I kind of feared... Still they might wanna change that considering the new law in the EU about data protection, cookie consent is getting even stricter here. I'll probably end up removing this facebook functionality because of the placed tracker....

Comment: Yeah, that EU cookie nonsense is an absolute p.i.t.a. ... I don’t think it actually benefits anyone (most users don’t care and simply get annoyed by the messages/confirmation dialog.) But you could implement login without the SDK, if you wanted ...

Comment: I agree, sigh. And I still can't do it only for the login, it's an SPA so all scripts are loaded on first contact. Loading the SDK when the user has accepted the policy is the same as just not implementing the facebook functionality with the exception that we might enable the functionality after the user accepted it (and then refresh the page or something like that).

Comment: _“it's an SPA so all scripts are loaded on first contact”_ - that should not stop you from loading the SDK only when needed ... you’d just have to modify the code that embeds it a little, so that it doesn’t run automatically, but only when you trigger it.

Comment: You're probably right, but I don't think I have the skill to do this within reasonable time. I am a backend developer only doing some easy frontend tasks when it's requested. I don't really know how to modify it... it's an AngularJS project, I can find the location where external and internal scripts are loaded in but it would cost me probably at least a day to find out how to conditionally load things in at a certain time - which is probably not worth whatever we're trying to do here.